# Setting up networking for KVM on Gentoo with exit to wifi adaṕter

Tags: networking, gentoo, kvm

I am running Gentoo Linux on an AMD64 laptop, and I am having an extremely hard time setting up host networking on KVM. I alreay have KVM, libvirtd, virt-manager, the kernel modules required to get virtualization working, and I already rebuilt my kernel with new configuration options according to [this guide here](http://big-elephants.com/2013-07/creating-virtual-networks-with-kvm-on-gentoo/), and I still cannot seem to be able to get host networking running.

I am able to create a VM using virt-manager, but I am unable to choose a network interface to connect my VM to, on virt-manager's final dialog under Advanced options, all the options on the drop-down box are disabled except "No networking" and "Specify shared device name". I cannot use bridge networking because my internet exit is through a wi-fi NIC.

I still can't get networking on KVM running. I do not want to use Oracle VM VirtualBox because I had a lot of problems with it in the past. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple script to setup my qemu devices in a private bridge (without the internet exit) and masquerade the traffic on the host:

```
/usr/sbin/brctl addbr qemu1
NET=10.116.64 # any private address you like
GW=1
BASE=0
MASK=24
ip addr add $NET.$GW/$MASK dev qemu1
ip link set qemu1 up
if iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING -n | grep ^MASQUERADE | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1 | grep "$NET.$BASE" >/dev/null
then
  echo "IP masquerading already set up"
else
  echo "Setting up IP masquerading"
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s "$NET.$BASE"/"$MASK" \! -d "$NET.$BASE"/"$MASK" -j MASQUERADE
fi
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
exit 0
```

To setup for each machine I use another simple script *use USER for the user who starts the vm*

```
#!/bin/sh
BRCTL=/usr/sbin/brctl
regif=$($BRCTL show $2|awk '/^\t/ { print $1; }' |grep "$1")
if [ x"$3" = "xstop" ]
then if [ x"$regif" != "x" ]
then
        ip link set $1 down
        /usr/sbin/openvpn --rmtun --dev $1
fi
elif [ x"$regif" = "x" ]
then
        /usr/sbin/openvpn --mktun --dev $1 --user USER
        ip link set $1 promisc on
        ip link set $1 up
        $BRCTL addif $2 $1
elif [ x"$3" = "xrestart" ]
then
        $0 $1 $2 stop # recursive call
        $0 $1 $2 # recursive call
fi
exit 0
```

called as `qemu-newif NAME_FOR_THE_TAP_DEVICE qemu1` to setup a tap device for each machine.